# How can symbols be formulated in metalanguage?

Tags: logic, formal-languages

In Tarski's Undefinability Theorem, a definition by the name of "Convention T" involves symbols formulated in metalanguage.

How is that possible? Shouldn't symbols be exclusive to formal languages? Doesn't the definition of metalanguage involve a language that is not composed of symbols?

Comment: Gödel coding of the language into integers?

Comment: What "definition of metalanguage" are you referring too? In the usual use of the term, there is no reason why a metalanguage should not be a formal language.

Comment: Metalanguage as "non-object language"